# Uncertainty of measurement with goniometer

Tags: standard-deviation

I got a goniometer with scale -90 to 90 degree. I use only 0 to 90 degree. One section of the scale has 1 degree. I read a value of $62^\circ$. What is the uncertainty of this measurement?

I thougt like this. If one section has $1^\circ$, then I can be mistaken by half of this value. I could put together range and this error as

$$\frac{90\cdot 0.5}{100 \sqrt{3}} =\pm~ 0.26^\circ$$

or

$$\frac{180\cdot 0.5}{100 \sqrt{3}} =\pm ~ 0.52^\circ$$

What do you think?

I asked this question on Electrical Engineering stack exchange, but they said it doesn't belong to that site. I asked in Physics stack exchange, but nobody responded. Shall I ask this question here?